# Case when SQL priority

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a query in which the records that have the priority column > 0 can be sorted by ASC priority, and the records that the priority column is 0, sorted by id DESC.

The way I did it works, but the DESC id ordering is being listed first than the priority order. Thus, the records with priority 0 are first. How to make the records with priority first?

see the code

`select * from registros  ORDER BY  CASE WHEN prioridade > 0 THEN prioridade END ASC,  id DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a two level sort here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM registros
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN prioridade > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN prioridade > 0 THEN prioridade ELSE -1*prioridade END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want something like this -

| Priority | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 2 |

You need to change your case statement so that records with priority 0 will be guaranteed to be last when sorted by ascending priority. The easiest way to do that is to hard code the sort value for priority 0 to some value higher than the highest priority (such as 999)

```
SELECT * 
FROM registros  
ORDER BY  
    CASE WHEN prioridade = 0 THEN 999 ELSE prioridade END ASC,
    id DESC
```